# KendoValidator is requiring fields that aren't actuallyrequired

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a field that isn't required shown below in code.  When I click save to post form data i get the kendo error message which should *only* validate that its a proper zipcode (it can be blank).  It also shows the error message when i tab away from the field which is not what I'm looking for.  Any help would be great, thanks!

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control " data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid Zip Code" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" id="ZipCode" name="ZipCode" onkeyup="enableButton()" tabindex="4" type="text" value="">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Form").kendoValidator();
    //$(".k-widget").removeClass("input-validation-error");
});
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is enableButton()?  I assume there's some other code we're not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.  It actually wasn't a Kendo issue, but a regex issue.

Regex makes a field required, but my regex data annotation wasn't accepting **empty strings**:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code")]
```

I added |^$ to the end of my regex and it solved my issue.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?|^$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Kendo Validator property 'validateOnBlur' to false (it defaults to true) to skip validation when the user tabs away.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Form").kendoValidator({
       validateOnBlur: false
     });
});
```

Also, I would use 'validationMessage' instead of 'data-val-regex', as well as 'pattern' instead of 'data-val-regex-pattern' in your input tag.

Finally, if you leave out the 'required' attribute, your user will be allowed to leave the field empty.

I've created a Dojo with a working example of this:  http://dojo.telerik.com/uPeQE

Comment: This is some very good info I will use in the future.  Let me ask you, why wouldyou choose validationMessage and pattern?  Also how would you implement them?  the data-val-regex and data-val-regex-pattern attributes are being added because of the data annotations in my model.

Comment: In that case you may want to continue using them if they are working for you.  I wasn't able to get it working in my example.  I had to use "pattern" and "validationMessage" per examples from Telerik:  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/overview